# How to load localization remotely using localizationsDelegates and show spinner while copy is loaded in flutter

Tags: flutter

Context:

1. Building my first Flutter app
2. It needs to be localized and I am not using intl package, but using the guidelines for LocalizationsDelegates (code below)
3. I want to load the localizations remotely from a server.
4. I want when my app starts to show a circular progress indicator right away, which stays until the copy has been loaded remotely fully and then the loading indicator to be dismissed.
5. I use provider for state management.
6. ... and I struggle to do that! :)

Here is my main and starting point stripped out of unnecessary lines to the Q:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => 'MyTitle',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const CopyDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('bg', ''),
      ],
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/': (BuildContext context) => Init(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the CopyDelegates class:

```
class CopyDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<Copy> {
  const CopyDelegate();

  //TODO change the source of supported languages
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) => ['en', 'bg'].contains(locale.languageCode);

  @override
  Future<Copy> load(Locale locale) async{
    Copy copy = Copy(locale);
    copy.load();
    return copy;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(CopyDelegate old) => false;
}
```

Copy is a simple class that doesn't inherit and in the `copy.load()` method I have my logic that fetches the localizations remotely. It's an `async` function with lots of 'await' statements that gets to the Remote Config, gets the copy URL, then downloads it from Firestore and parses it as a JSON string that is loaded into a Map. `Copy` then provides methods to retrieve the loaded strings.

Finally, here is the 'Init' widget stripped of other stuff:

```
class Init extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      //TODO add logic to transition away from spinner when copy has loaded          
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
   }
 }
```

The main issue I have is:

- How do I notify 'Init' widget once my copy state has changed, i.e. when 'copy.load()' has finished all its async calls, so that I can transition away from the loading spinner?

Comment: Btw, one thought I had was to turn 'Copy' into a ChangeNotifier and then 'notifyListeneres()' from inside its 'load()' method, but I don't see it clearly how I would get the 'Init' wisget to update as I don't have the instance of 'Copy' since I don't create it, but the framework does at some point...